# how to give image path in java script in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

i am using asp.net mvc for my project. i am using partial views for that i used ajax jaquery every thing is working fine but i am not getting image for loading when i upload an image. image get displyed at local host it has problem when i upload the project.
i have given image as:

```
$jq("#ajaxThrobber").html('<img src="/Images/ajax-loader.gif"> Loading.....');
```

please advice me thank you.

Comment: Can you post the code where this code is in relation to the code that makes the server request?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i got the solution use two dots before image path.

```
$jq("#ajaxThrobber").html('<img src="../Images/ajax-loader.gif"> Loading.....');
```